# Python Scrapy- Not able to crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl some websites using scrapy. Below is a sample code. The method parse is not getting called. I am trying to run the code through a reactor service ( code provided ). So, I run it from startCrawling.py which has the reactor. I know that I am missing something. Could you please help out.

Thanks,

```
Code-categorization.py

from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from items.items import CategorizationItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider
class TestingSpider(CrawlSpider):
         print 'in spider'
         name = 'testSpider'
         allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
         start_urls = ['http://www.wikipedia.org']
         def parse(self, response):

             # Scrape data from page
             print 'here'
             open('test.html','wb').write(response.body)
```

Code- startCrawling.py

```
 from twisted.internet import reactor
 from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
 from scrapy.settings import Settings
 from scrapy import log, signals
 from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
 from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

 from spiders.categorization import TestingSpider

 # Scrapy spiders script...

 def stop_reactor():
     reactor.stop #@UndefinedVariable    
     print 'hi'

     dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed) 
     spider = TestingSpider()
     crawler = Crawler(Settings())
     crawler.configure()
     crawler.crawl(spider)
     crawler.start()
     reactor.run()#@UndefinedVariable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to override the `parse()` method when using the `CrawlSpider`. You should set a custom `callback` in your `Rule` with a different name.
Here is the excerpt from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Comment: Thank you. I am accepting the answer right away. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: The fastest accept ever, I just clicked and it turned green :)